# Getting error when trying to build unity project with xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

[image: Build log]
When i'm trying to build unity project im getting the error.

I can fix that with creating a new unity project and transfering all assets from old project to new, but i want to know what the reason of this error and fix it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.